# I cannot use Alt-Tab to switch between windows in Arch Linux with Budgie Desktop

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, budgie

I installed budgie desktop on Endeavour OS (based on Arch Linux) using the package manager (yay). I am unable to switch between applications using alt-tab. Also, the control panel does not open. How can I enable alt-tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have budgie-extras installed to make alt-tab work just pure Budgie and control center wont do the trick.